# How to set priority for executing functions inside an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a button click event like this,
I want to execute 'each function' before 'CategoryCombo(count)'

```js
  $('body').on('click', '.btnEdit', function () {
    
      $(".DetailsTB tr").each(function () {
        ......
      });
        
      CategoryCombo(count);
    
  }
```

Comment: It will execute as you said. I can't understand your problem.

Comment: at first it executes categorycombo();
I want to execute categorycombo() after each function

Comment: Nah.. That won't. do you have any `async calls` inside of each function?

Comment: iam using ajax inside function categorycombo()

Comment: I suggest looking at promises approach